# Trying to get object property but i get the "Trying to get property 'status' of non-object"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get a particular column data and check if a the status is confirmed by running it through an if statement but I get the "Trying to get property 'status' of non-object" error

This is my controller;

```
public function transaction(Request $request){
        request()->validate([
            'amount' => 'required'
        ]);
        $trans = Transaction::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        if(Auth::user()->transaction && !$trans->status){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error", "You currently have a withdrawal request pending confirmation");
        }
        if($request->input('amount') > Auth::user()->balance){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error", "Insufficient balance to complete request");
        }
        Mail::to('mail@gmail.com')->send(new transaction($request));

        $transaction->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Your withdrawal request has successfully been received");


    }
```

My transaction model;

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check whether the record exists or not.
Use the below code before accessing the status property on the object and confirm you have received the data from the database.

```
if(!$trans) {
    return abort(404); // record does not exists
}
```

The reason of the error is the data is not returned by your query.
The $trans variable contains the null, that is the reason you got the error **Trying to get property 'status' of non-object**.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the $trans object exists.
Change your code to this:

```
 if(empty($trans) || (Auth::user()->transaction && !$trans->status)) {
        return redirect()->back()->with("error", "You currently have a withdrawal request pending confirmation");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's where the problem was. fixed now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After this line
`$trans = Transaction::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`
Check for this 
`if($trans == '' || $trans == null) {
return redirect()->back()->with("error", "No trans available");
}